# Can changing a function which used to return a const ref to an std::string to return by value break calling code?

Tags: c++

We have a function like so:

```
const std::string& ConvertToString(Enum e)
{
    static const std::string enumStrings[4] =
    {
        std::string("first"),
        std::string("second"),
        std::string("third"),
        std::string("unknown")
    }

    int enumOrd = static_cast<int>(e);
    if (e < 0 || e > 2)
    {
        return enumStrings[3];
    }

    return enumStrings[enumOrd];
}
```

Now, the problem is that this function is being called after main() returns, and it's crashing since that static array has already been destroyed. I want to change it to be like so:

```
std::string ConvertToString(Enum e)
{
    switch (static_cast<int>(e))
    {
        case 0: return std::string("first");
        case 1: return std::string("second");
        case 2: return std::string("third");
        default: return std::string("unknown");
    }
}
```

I wondering if it's possible for this change to break any code which calls this function. I can't think of any problems (as long as the class being returned didn't do sneaky things in const methods, but std::string should be fine, especially in the transition of const ref -> value, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: If you returned by const ref to save a copy, don't. I can't immediately think of any broken code by this, but returning by value is typically more preferable.

Comment: Don't try to be clever by doing big things in global constructors or destructors. It results in headaches like these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way this could go wrong is if the calling code does something like:

```
const char* s = ConvertToString(first).c_str();
```

And then stores `s` somewhere and accesses it later, thinking that the `std::string` object referenced by the return value of `ConvertToString` will never be destroyed.

Of course, that calling code sucks anyway, in that case.

Comment: Wouldn't that have been broken in the first place?

Comment: No, because if `ConvertToString` returned a const reference to a statically allocated `std::string` object, then `s` would remain valid.

Comment: @chris no, the `c_str()` would last as long as the `static` array in the function in the original code.

Comment: Pardon me, I didn't catch the static.

Answer (score 2):

You can break code that depends on different calls to `ConvertToString` yielding the same object:

```
for (std::string::const_iterator it = ConvertToString(first).begin();
     it != ConvertToString(first).end(); ++it) {
   // undefined behavior: cannot compare iterators referring 
   // to two different containers/strings
}
```

One other side note, your implementation might not do what you expect. In particular if your enumeration is defined as `enum Enum { first, second, third };` the code:

```
if (e < 0 || e > 2) {
   return enumStrings[3];
}
```

can be completely removed by an optimizing compiler and `unknown` might never be returned by the function. The reason is that the `Enum` enumeration cannot legally hold any value that is not the bitmask of the enumerators (in this case: 0, 1, 2, 3). Doing so is undefined behavior. The compiler can use this knowledge to optimize the code and remove the `e < 0` and/or convert the test condition into a single `e == 3`.

Comment: He can just replace `e` with `enumOrd` to remove the possibility of that optimization

Comment: @CharlesSalvia: Trying to fight the optimizer is a big task. The optimizer sees that `enumOrd` is initialized out of `e`, so it knows that it cannot hold any value other than the above given. Once the optimizer bites you once you learn to respect it. An interesting read [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Comment: Looking at the Standard, it's not the bitmask of the enumerators, but the smallest bitfield capable of holding all the values (alternatively, the bitmask with interior holes removed).